# Android on Onclick not working

Tags: android

I have two buttons on my android app. One works perfectly (ViewLogs) the other (OfflineSync) does not - the code is the same and I get no errors?

```
package com.teamtba.hcpm;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class ViewLogs extends Activity {



//Buttons
Button ViewLogs;
Button btnOfflineSync;







@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_account)

        btnOfflineSync = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSyncOffline);

        ViewLogs = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCreateLog);
        // Hashmap for ListView    
        btnOfflineSync.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent tr = new Intent(ViewLogs.this, CreateLog.class);
                startActivity(tr);
            }
        });

        ViewLogs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ViewLogs.this, CreateLog.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        });



        btnOfflineSync.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I've cut out the other code that is in there but if you want to see it I can post it (it's mainly just other functions that don't call the button.

I've tried via XML but it generates an error everytime and crashes the app.

Comment: Please define not working. The code highlighting makes ViewLogs look like it's not a button variable name. Why aren't you writing *viewLogs instead?

Comment: When I click the Syncoffline button nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `btnOfflineSync.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

How are you sending onClick event?

Comment: Oh how embarrassing. I had an if statement (not shown here) to check if the user was connected if not it was to hide the button. I had the declaration for the onclick with that IF statement thus the view of the button was hidden. I have accpeted your post as an answer sadly I can't upvote just yet. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Class name **ViewLogs** and button name **ViewLogs**  are same, change button name to something

Answer (score 0):

**- First remarque :**

The activity has the same name as the button so try to change the name of the button (to viewLogs)

**- Second remarque :** 
the action of the two buttons has the same function (intent to start CreateLogs.class) .
So, you can use one function (onClick):

```
btnOfflineSync.setOnClickListener(this);
viewLogs.setOnClickListener(this);
//
}
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent tr = new Intent(ViewLogs.this, CreateLog.class);
                startActivity(tr);
}
```

and don't forget to implement  `OnClickListener`

**- Third remarque:**

you write `btnOfflineSync.setVisibility(View.GONE);` after the onclickListener (??) How are you sending onClick event ? you can remove this line , an make your button visible

```
public class ViewLogs extends Activity {

//Buttons
Button viewLogs; //button name changed
Button btnOfflineSync;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_account)

        btnOfflineSync = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSyncOffline);

        viewLogs = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCreateLog); //button name changed
        // Hashmap for ListView    
        btnOfflineSync.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent tr = new Intent(ViewLogs.this, CreateLog.class);
                startActivity(tr);
            }
        });

        viewLogs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ViewLogs.this, CreateLog.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        });
```